# members occurrences not showing in scroll bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I used to use this feature to see the number of occurances and position of a type or member. It supposed to work when I click a member and it's highlighted in grey, and all the occurrences drawn along the scroll bar as grey dots, representing the number of occurrences and their positions. Now I miss this helpful feature, and the only way to use it, is to copy the member name and paste it in the Find window. How to bring it back to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

To change the scroll bar mode, right click on the scroll bar itself and choose Scroll Bar Options from the context menu. You could also locate the scroll bar settings by typing “scroll bar” in the Quick Launch, or by navigating to Tools | Options | Text Editor | All Languages | Scroll Bars from the menu